# Entity types created via ECK (Entity Construction Kit) is in code or in DB?

Tags: 7, entities

There is a lot of great articles around creating new entity types like [this](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/creating-own-entities-entity-api)

also there is module named ECK, I would like know what is the result of this?

And how is efferent from creating entity types via module, in performance and functionality?